# Creating rough mesh colliders for objects in Unity

Tags: mesh, unity, geometry

Hello fellow blender users,

I'm working on a big scene in a science project, a city with over 200 houses, streets, walls, and all that good stuff that's appearing in a city scene. The whole scene gets imported to Unity and the objects need mesh colliders to give us proper eye-tracking data.
For the houses I've created meshes by hand and assigned them as mesh colliders on the object in Unity. But now we have a lot of fences and walls created with curves and it would take a lot of time to create mesh colliders by hand for all these objects.

[image]

In the middle of the scene I've added an example of a fence-like object and tried around with a remesh and decimate modifier to create somehow a collider. Now my question is:
is there a way to create from the mesh in the middle a mesh-like on the right with modifiers or any operation? Like taking the max transform values of points and generating a mesh of a certain poly count or anything? I was not sure for what to search in the forums so maybe I'm just blind.

Comment: I don't know what kind of accuracy you want, but you could try the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: Not really a full solution, but in edit mode, there is a handy little operator: _Mesh → Convex Hull._